# [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [skillbillchannel] creator org [Org1MSP]

Tags: azure, hyperledger-fabric

I was trying to query the data ledger on Azure Hyperledger Fabric and I ran the scripts: enrollAdmin.js and registerUser.js successfully, but I failed to query the data (node query.js) and got error:**[client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [skillbillchannel] creator org [Org1MSP].**

error from query =  ***{ Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [skillbillchannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/skillbilladmin/blockchain_dapp/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/skillbilladmin/blockchain_dapp/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1214:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/skillbilladmin/blockchain_dapp/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:590:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/skillbilladmin/blockchain_dapp/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:640:8)
    at callback (/home/skillbilladmin/blockchain_dapp/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:867:24)
  code: 2,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'access denied: channel [skillbillchannel] creator org [Org1MSP]' }***

And here is logs from peer container when I queried and got the error:

*2018-06-11 04:16:04.071 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 040 channel [skillbillchannel]: MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

2018-06-11 06:34:43.331 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 041 channel [skillbillchannel]: MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority*

P/s: I have 1 CA, 1 Orderer, 2 Peers, 1 CLi and started successfully.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: any idea? I'm facing same issue